# Block non logged in users from accessing the media library

Tags: media-library, session

I have a custom login page for a site I'm working on that isn't related to the backend login. The purpose of this is so users that aren't logged in cannot see the site. When the site loads it looks for a session and if non exists, it redirects the user to the login page and that's all they can see. This all works great, but is there an easy way to also disable non logged in users from accessing the Media Library? Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are new users being allowed access to your WP dashboard? If you give the permission role of "Subscriber" to your users they won't be able to access the dashboard (including Media Library). Or is there something else you're meaning by Media Library? Also is there a particular reason you want a separate login system?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want them to be able to see the backend Media Library pages (ie the list of uploaded files), or you don't want them to see images, PDFs, etc on the frontend (eg like a membership site)?

Comment: @PatJ it'd be like a membership site. If they aren't registered then they should not be able to take an image url from the site to view it.

Comment: @YourManDan this was a client request to have a separate login so non registered users couldn't see the front end until they signed up.

Comment: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658988/prevent-direct-access-to-images-using-the-browser-url) StackOverflow article that might help if you wanted a pure code solution. Also found [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-direct-access/) plugin that appears to do what you're wanting.

Comment: when you say a session can you be more specific? And by media library I assume you actually mean files in `wp-contents/uploads`? Most server configurations are set up to send browsers straight to the file without WordPress being loaded, so you can't solve this with just PHP, it would need your hosts cooperation

Comment: @TomJNowell exactly I mean the files in `wp-contents/uploads`. I figured this wouldn't be an easy feat. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: the easiest path is to modify your Nginx configs or Apache configuration to only allow access if certain cookies are set, but that's beyond the scope of WordPress, assuming you have the necessary access. It also means any images uploaded and used in the theme/frontend won't show either, neither will anything plugins put in there, so be careful with testing